# PHP allowed memory size message doesnot make sense (requested smaller than allowed)

Tags: php

I am getting this message:

```
 Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10489856 bytes) in /home/MY_USER/public_html/application/views/ms/somefile.php
```

If I convert the sizes in megabytes it does not make sense because it will read as follows:

```
Allowed memory size of 138 Mega-bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10.4 Mega-bytes) in /home/MY_USER/public_html/application/views/ms/somefile.php
```

so my script is exiting because it is trying to allocated 10.4 mega-bytes which is exceeding the allowed 138 mega-bytes?

I am totally lost here.

Update:
[image]

I already had my memory at 512MB but it is reporting it is being capped at 138MB. I have it set in the WHM for that specific PHP version.

Note: I am running in PHP-FPM setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration

- settings of the memory limit can be set on various places in your configuration aka `php.ini`, `.htacces`, `.user.ini`, or the php script itself via [`ini_set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set) function.
- there are different configuration loaded when running PHP, ie `CLI` vs `CGI` [CGI and command line setups](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.commandline.php)

If your settings of `memory_limit` is set to 512M and your script fail to allocate 138M this sounds like your script is using different configuration than you have on the screenshot, see the CGI vs CLI above.

Troubleshooting

Try to run `php_info()` within your php script `/home/MY_USER/public_html/application/views/ms/somefile.php` to see what configuration is used by your script.

Try to temporary set the more generous memory limit using `ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');` within your `../somefile.php` script.

To get an idea how much memory your scrip needs you may print the final memory usage using PHP functions [memory_get_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) `echo memory_get_usage().' bytes.';` and/or [memory_peak_usage()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) 
At the same time print the peak memory usage using `echo memory_peak_usage() .' bytes.';`

Comment: there was a random "ini_set()" thrown in the script that was capping the memory. Thx a ton.

Answer (score 1):

The "tried to allocate" amount is how much you tried to add when exceeding the limit, not the total you tried to reach.

So this means that at the time of the error, you were already using between 128 and 138 MB, and you tried to allocate another 10.4 MB. 128+10.4 would be more than 138, so it exceeds the memory size limit.

Comment: that makes sense now. The problem is I am using php-fpm (WHM). and in WHM i have the memory set to 512 mega-bytes. But it is reporting that 138 MB limit. Any idea on where to look for it? (I already added the pic to the original post).

Comment: If you do `echo ini_get('memory_limit');` in the script, does it show the 512MB value?

Comment: i will double check on that and see what turns out